# How to check if value is included in hash in ActiveRecord validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Project` model and I need to test if the `billing_address_type` is valid.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :billing_address_type, :inclusion  => { :in => %w(h o) }

  def billing_address_types
    options = {"Home" => "h", "Organisation" => "o"}       
    if person.present?
      options.delete("Home") if person.address.blank?
      options.delete("Organisation") if person.organisation.blank?
    end
    options
  end
```

The `validates` line is wrong, however. I need to check for inclusion of the hash values returned by the method `billing_address_types`.

How can I check for the hash values only?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: You need has_value? method if i understand you write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass [`lambda`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) or a new [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) to the `:in` option which will be dynamically evaluated, and use the [`values`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of) method on the hash returned from `billing_address_types` to get the hash values only:

```
validates :billing_address_type, :inclusion  => { :in => lambda { |a| a.class.billing_address_types.values } }
```

See the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_inclusion_of) for details.